# Adding values to an object within an Array inside a FOR loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array extracted from Mongo in the following form

```
[
  {
    _id: 60d51d210e5e4e297066132a,
    MemberName: 'Name of Member',
    MemberRank: 25,
    MemberFDR: 6.43,
    MemberImageurl: 'uploads/images/gauravverma.jpg'
  },
  {
    _id: 60d5c619c163f23195e01d00,
    MemberName: 'Name Of Member',
    MemberRank: 24,
    MemberFDR: 6.5,
    MemberImageurl: 'uploads/images/shashikhanna.jpeg'
  },
]
```

After extracting the original array, I am looping through the array, extracting the name of the member and then doing some more queries in the DB. The length of this returned query, is the count and I want to add it in the original object like so

```
[
      {
        _id: 60d51d210e5e4e297066132a,
        MemberName: 'Name of Member',
        MemberRank: 25,
        MemberFDR: 6.43,
        MemberImageurl: 'uploads/images/gauravverma.jpg',
        Count: 3(whatever the length of the array will be)
      },
      {
        _id: 60d5c619c163f23195e01d00,
        MemberName: 'Name Of Member',
        MemberRank: 24,
        MemberFDR: 6.5,
        MemberImageurl: 'uploads/images/shashikhanna.jpeg'
        Count: 5(whatever the length of the array will be)
      },
    ]
```

My query returns the value perfectly, I am struggling with how to insert the value in the original object.

```
let memberName
  let countOfCurrentChallengeMatches
  for(let i=0; i<challengeList.length; ){
    console.log("hi i am here 1")
    memberName = challengeList[i].MemberName
    console.log(memberName)
    try {
      console.log(memberName)
      countOfCurrentChallengeMatches = await MatchRegister.find({
        $and: [
          { $or: [{ChallengingPlayer: memberName},{ChallengedPlayer: memberName}] },
          { $or: [{ChallengeStatus: 'Awaiting Score Approval'},{ChallengeStatus: 'Accepted'},{ChallengeStatus: 'Completed'}, {ChallengeStatus: 'Issued'}] },
          {ChallengerMonth: cMonth},
        ],
    },'_id ChallengingPlayer ChallengedPlayer ChallengerMonth ChallengerYear ProposedChallengeDate ProposedChallengeTime ChallengeMatchLocation ChallengeStatus MatchFormat RejectionReason')
    .sort({ProposedChallengeDate: 1}).exec()
    } catch (err) {
      const error = new HttpError(
        'Something went wrong, could not update member.',
        500
      );
      return next(error);
    }
        // Here is where i want to insert the value in the object

    i++
  }
```

I have tried options like, push, add and a few other options from google, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Just example below. Have you tried this example yet?

```html
var arrOfObj = [{
  name: 'eve'
}, {
  name: 'john'
}, {
  name: 'jane'
}];

var result = arrOfObj.map(function(el) {
  var o = Object.assign({}, el);
  o.isActive = true;
  return o;
})

console.log(arrOfObj);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this simple line worked. Not sue why I missed it in my research

```
challengeList[i].count = countOfCurrentChallengeMatches.length
```